# css percentage of outer width

Tags: css

I need to achieve literaly what `position:sticky` does, but I cannot use it because of compatibility with older browsers.

I have a container, which scrollbar has to be on its edge, but the content is only 80% of width.
Inside this main container are two parts: menu and content container. If I could use sticky positioning, i would put menu inside content container, made it 100% width and problem solved.

But I can not, so I need to put the menu outside of the scrolling content container, and there where problems with sizing begins:
MENU takes 80% of main container width, which has no scrollbar
CONTENT inside scrolling content container takes 80% of container content, but without scrollbar counted.

For demonstration, here is a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ww58qLcw/3/

So, any idea, how to set the width of content to 80% of outer width, including the scrollbar?

Thanks in advance.

//edit:updated fiddle

Comment: What's wrong in the fiddle?

Comment: this behavior is same for all common desktop browsers. FF, Opera, Chrome, Edge..... and position:sticky is not usable because of no support in older versions of Edge and all the IEs

Comment: You can use a polyfill called [stickyfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill). I used it a couple of times, works great.

Comment: @GerardReches the width of menu is not the same as the content, as the menu takes 80% of .container and contentin takes 80% of content - which is 100% of .container, but 100% of content is .container-scrollbar

Comment: @Zorak [My face right now](http://mxcdn02.mundotkm.com/2016/02/dientesh.jpg) trying to understand that pun. So you just want `.menu` to be the same width as `.content`?

Comment: Yes. It should appear like a single block. But as I said, if you set a percentage width, it takes the inner, not the outer width. So, if .content is scrollable, its inner width is smaller by the width of its scrollbar, and that is the core of the problem. Then, if I set .contentin 80%, theese 80% are smaller than the .menu 80%, because of that scrollbar, even .content is 100% of .container

Comment: @Zorak Ah! Now I understand. Nice challenge, trying to find a solution.

Comment: I think there is no CSS only solution.. Using javascript you could check for the `.content` width and its left margin to adjust the `.menu` width and left position.

Comment: Yep, this I want to avoid the scripted solution, really hoped there will be pure HTML/CSS way. Anyway, thanks for trying :)

Comment: I don't get why you don't use a polyfill for `sticky`?

Comment: for actually 3 reasons: 1) didn't know about this plugin till this question. 2) Don't want to load whole library just because of 1 div 3) I am working with ooverflow divs in my project, and like that it will not work, as its documentation says ... I will need to code my own solution

Answer (score 1):

Can you possibly do a `calc` on the width of the menu? In the jsfiddle, I was able to get the menu to be the same width as the container by adjusting the width to `width: calc(80% - 16px);`. Which assumes the scrollbar is about 16px wide. So both menu and container are affected by the width of scrollbar, instead of just one.

Comment: Sadly, it is not possible, as every browser has different scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure exactly what you were going for but see the CSS adjustments below.

```
.container{position:relative; margin:10px auto auto auto; width:80%; height:400px; border:1px solid black; background:#eee; }
.menu{background:green; position:absolute; top:0; left:17.7%; width:61.7%; height:30px;z-index:1;  color:yellow;}
.content{width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; margin:auto; overflow-y:scroll;}
.contentin{position:relative; margin:auto; width:80%; background:aqua; padding-top:30px; z-index:0; min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Sadly, will not work, I need the menu same width as content. Also, try to resize your browser. Even it has the same distance from the edges, as you resize the window, left and right space will differ - that is because % is always %, but the scrollbar is fixed size, so it will mess with final outcome.